# Google AppEngine with Service Account but invalid Credentials

Tags: python, google-app-engine, service-accounts, google-groups-settings

I have tried to get a group settings with group settings API using Google App Engine 1.7.5 with python 2.5 following a simple example [here](https://code.google.com/p/mlab-metrics-api-server/source/browse/examples/app_assertion_credentials/).
this is my app.yaml:

```
application: {{APP_ID}}
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

and my main.py is like following:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', TestHandler)])
    run_wsgi_app(application)

class TestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    """Handles a request for the query page."""
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(Test())

def Test():
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings')
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
    service = build('groupssettings', 'v1', http=http)
    group = service.groups().get(groupUniqueId='{{GROUP_ID}}').execute()
    logging.error(group)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and this is the stacktrace telling me invalid credentials!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 714, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "D:\Projets\GS\main.py", line 26, in get
    self.response.out.write(Test())
  File "D:\Projets\GS\main.py", line 41, in Test
    group = service.groups().get(groupUniqueId='{{GROUP_ID}}').execute()
  File "D:\Projets\GS\oauth2client\util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projets\GS\apiclient\http.py", line 723, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/{{GROUP_ID}}?alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials">
INFO     2014-11-21 15:51:45,423 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-11-21 15:51:45,611 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Have anyone got this error before or have an idea of the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on access to the groups API through the developer console for the project? This is a simple step that is often missed by people trying to get APIs going.

Also, I'd recommend using the decorator patterns for OAuth [as described here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine) to simplify the reasoning around authorization flows.

In addition, your app.yaml should specify `python27` rather than just `python`. App Engine runs `python27`.

Comment: I have already add and authorize the GroupSettings API in the console, but how to do the authorization CPanel inside ? i tried to authorize {{APP_ID}}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com to the same scope but dont get it saying that the URL should contain host.

Comment: Yes - we are having this problem too - and turning on the GroupSettings API made no difference.

Comment: Just to be clear, `{{GROUP_ID}}` in your question refers to the email address of the group you're trying to get, but you made it anonymized for the question?